# Testing parameters of a password in assembly

Tags: assembly

Good morning, you could help me, I have a problem looking for if an assembly character is a special character or a number. I give you an example of the program that does not work:

```
testing macro  

     cmp al, 30h      ;number
     jl NAD1            
     cmp al, 39h            
     jg NAD1
     inc number
     jmp NAD1      
     NAD1:

     cmp al, 21h     ;special char
     jg 1
     1:      
     cmp al, 2Fh           
     jl INCREMENT

     cmp al, 3Ah
     jg 2
     2:      
     cmp al, 40h           
     jl INCREMENT

     cmp al, 5Bh
     jg INCREMENT      
     cmp al,60h           
     jl INCREMENT  

     cmp al, 7Bh
     jg 3
     3:      
     cmp al, 7Eh          
     jl INCREMENT          

     jmp NAD2

     INCREMENT:          
     inc specialchar
     jmp NAD2      
     NAD2:

     cmp al, 41h     ;uppercase       
     jl NAD3            
     cmp al, 5Ah            
     jg NAD3
     inc uppercase
     jmp NAD3      
     NAD3: 

endm
```

I have some counters like number,m specialchar and .....
In al is my character.
I hope with a ascii table intervals.

Comment: _"program that does not work"_ Does not work _how_?

Comment: Why is this macro? This looks like regular code. Also provide definition, what should be result, because at this moment any digit will increment both `number` and `specialchar`, which you probably don't want? BTW: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/  (use debugger yourself to see how the flow does change for various `al` values, in some cases your code makes very little sense, like `jg 1` jumping at the next line, making it equivalent to `nop` instruction, because in both cases (less+equal and greater) it will end on next line, so the jump is useless).

Answer (score 1):

This is how the ASCII table looks like:

```
00h..20h Invalid
21h..2Fh Special   !"#$%&'()*+,-./
30h..39h Number    0123456789
3Ah..40h Special   :;<=>?@
41h..5Ah Uppercase ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
5Bh..60h Special   [\]^_`
61h..7Ah Lowercase abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
7Bh..7Eh Special   {|}~
7Fh..FFh Invalid
```

ASCII codes are unsigned numbers!

- Don't use `jl` (jump if less) but use `jb` (jump if below)
- Don't use `jg` (jump if greater) but use `ja` (jump if above)

---

Successively compare `AL` to the lower bound of each range. If `below` then the character belongs to the lower range.
See that you can fill in the missing part!

```
    cmp al, 21h
    jb  Invalid   ; Codes 00h..20h leave here
    cmp al, 30h
    jb  Special   ; Codes 21h..2Fh leave here








    cmp al, 7Bh
    jb  Lowercase ;
    cmp al, 7Fh
    jb  Special   ; Codes 7Bh..7Eh leave here
                  ; For the codes 7Fh..FFh we conveniently fall through
Invalid:
    ...
    jmp Done
Special:
    ...
    jmp Done
Number:
    inc number
    jmp Done
Uppercase:
    ...
    jmp Done
Lowercase:
    ...
Done:
    ...
```

It's important that you don't fall through in the code that is beneath. That's why each case ends with a jump to the *Done* label.
The exception here is the *Lowercase* case because writing

```
    jmp Done
Done:
```

would be silly.